# Why sys.sp_describe_first_result_set return 1 on very first time- not always?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-administration

SSIS package for import csv file has been configured with SQL server agent which run every 2 min.

Experiencing, SQL process suspended with result sys.sp_describe_first_result_set;1

**When** : ONLY at VERY first time (when Azure VM created) with more than one csv file import.

**When not** :

1. If any single CSV file import has happen before.
2. If point 1 has been followed , we can rapid import any number of csv file.(no sql suspend)

[image]

**SQL Process suspended with** sys.sp_describe_first_result_set return 1

**Details of suspended :**

**Blkby** = -2 = orphaned distributed transaction

**Suspended** : session is waiting for an event to complete

**Command** : Execute

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show how exactly you are executing `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set`?

Comment: activity monitor -> right click on suspended process -> details you will get @gotqn

Comment: I mean with what parameters

Comment: I am not executing,  system is showing suspend details sys.sp_describe_first_result_set ;1 when importing 2 csv file at very first time. either by manual or schedule job run

Comment: experience all ok ,when i ran job first time with single csv file import subsequently any number of csv file import.  I suspect optimization time error but not sure how to explore and fix @gotqn

Comment: `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set ;1` looks like it is calling it as a numbered stored procedure. Not that it is returning a result set with 1 and that 1 happens to correspond to that 1 in the text you have found. i.e. it is calling it in the same way as `exec sys.sp_describe_first_result_set;1 N'SELECT 1 AS X'`

Comment: sys.sp_describe_first_result_set ;1 means error 
sys.sp_describe_first_result_set ;0 means success 
and 
There are many cause of error 1 , please follow below link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
@MartinSmith

Comment: No you are misunderstanding `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set ;1` only shows the call to the proc. It doesn't tell you anything about what it returns. That is the command that was executed. There is no concatenation of any return code happening. If it is indeed hung as you suggest then presumably it hasn't actually returned anything yet.

Comment: If it is hung you need to look and see what wait types the session executing that command is getting whilst it is showing up as suspended

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith below is detail of hung / suspended 
Blkby = -2 = orphaned distributed transaction
Suspended : session is waiting for an event to complete
Command : Execute
It is only very first time / not always

Comment: @MartinSmith, Please have look on detail of hung

Comment: So you'll need to troubleshoot why you've got an orphaned distributed transaction then and deal with that. maybe look at https://www.eraofdata.com/sql-server/troubleshooting-sql-server/orphaned-msdtc-transactions-2-spids/

Comment: @MartinSmith  Thanks for update, my issue was in SSIS package code - unnecessary transaction for multiple sql task which caused db lock and solution is in below link 
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-transactions?view=sql-server-ver16

<DTS:TransactionOptionOption = "0"
NotSupported : 0
Supported : 1
Required : 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by removing <DTS:TransactionOption = "2" from SSIS package

It was not properly implemented in my case ,follow for more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-transactions?view=sql-server-ver16

Below are TransactionOption values
NotSupported : 0 Supported : 1 Required : 2